# What is the "official" stance on the theory of structural dissociation?

Tags: personality, abnormal-psychology, dissociation

From what I have heard, Nijenhuis's research is questionable, and ridden with abusive practices. Moreover, lots of the information that I am finding on this subject is sourced to biased seeming sources, that make a number of questionable claims about D.I.D (such as that D.I.D is not a result of trauma, that it is not rare, or that alters to talk to one another in a mental "headspace").
So I am curious, how does clinical psychology react to the theory of structural dissociation, and more broadly, what is the official stance on D.I.D?

Answer (score 1):

The most recent DSM recognizes DID but there is still controversy regarding existence and diagnosis.

https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/psych-unseen/202302/the-debate-over-whether-dissociative-identity-disorder-is-real?amp

“Dissociative identity disorder is part of the larger dissociative disorders spectrum; however, it has more specific criteria outlined by the Diagnostic And Statistical Manual Edition-5. The Diagnostic and Statistical Manual (DSM-5)criteria for DID include at least two or more distinct personalities.”

[https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK568768/#:~:text=%5B10%5D%20Dissociative%20identity%20disorder%20is,two%20or%20more%20distinct%20personalities](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK568768/#:%7E:text=%5B10%5D%20Dissociative%20identity%20disorder%20is,two%20or%20more%20distinct%20personalities).